# JqueryUI DateTimePicker buttons stop working after appending html from dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm having this issue with my datetimepicker that stops working after appending an html table.

I have a button that opens a dialog. This contains fields to enter and when clicking Save it adds the values as a record to an html table.
That works fine, however, when opening the dialog again, the datetimepicker buttons don't work anymore.

The dialog form has multiple datetimepickers, however, I simplified an example of the issue.

Please see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VytfY/450/) below for an example.

```
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", timeFormat: "HH:mm", hourMin: 0, hourMax: 24, stepMinute: 10
    });

    var dialog;

    dialog = $("#addnewDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 250,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Save": addnewrec,
            Cancel: function () {
                dialog.dialog("close");
            }
        },
        open : function() {

        },
        close: function () {

        }
    });

    $("#AddNew").button().on("click", function () {
        dialog.dialog("open");
    });

    function addnewrec() {
        var valid = true;

        var dealerref = $('#tblInput').find('#DealerRef').val();
        var dtCreated = $('#tblInput').find('#DTCreated').val();

        if (valid) {

            var td1 = '<td id=DealerRef>' + dealerref + '</td>';
            var td2 = '<td id=DTCreated>' + dtCreated + '</td>';

            $("#tblStyle tbody").append("<tr><td></td>" +
                td1 + td2 + "</tr>");

            dialog.dialog("close");
        }

        return valid;
    }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VytfY/450/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is beacause you're genrating in the table `td`'s with the same id as your datepicker id , so it works first time then after appending td into the table , the select on timepicker will throw an error due to duplicate id items

Also know that in an HTML page you should always use ID for one and only one element otherwise use classes .

You can fix this last by generating changine timepicker id or genrate other id's for `td's` by incrementation for example :

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/2rkw090g/1/)

Snippet :

```js
$(function () {

        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", timeFormat: "HH:mm", hourMin: 0, hourMax: 24, stepMinute: 10
        });
        var increment = 0;
        var dialog;

        dialog = $("#addnewDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 250,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Save": addnewrec,
                Cancel: function () {
                    dialog.dialog("close");
                }
            },
            open : function() {
               
            },
            close: function () {

            }
        });

        $("#AddNew").button().on("click", function () {
            dialog.dialog("open");
        });

        function addnewrec() {
            var valid = true;

            var dealerref = $('#tblInput').find('#DealerRef').val();
            var dtCreated = $('#tblInput').find('#DTCreated').val();
         
            if (valid) {
        increment++;
                var td1 = '<td id=DealerRef'+increment+'>' + dealerref + '</td>';
                var td2 = '<td id=DTCreated'+increment+'>' + dtCreated + '</td>';
               
                $("#tblStyle tbody").append("<tr><td></td>" +
                    td1 + td2 + "</tr>");

                dialog.dialog("close");
            }

            return valid;
        }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="AddNew" type="button" value="Add New Activity" class="btn btn-default" />
        <br /><br />
    <div id="addnewDialog" title="Add New Activity">
    
     <table id="tblInput">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        DealerRef
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <input id="DealerRef" name="DealerRef" type="text" value="">
                    </td>                                   
                </tr>               
                <tr>                   
                  <td>
                    DTCreated
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input class="datepicker" id="DTCreated" name="DTCreated" type="text" value="">
                  </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    
     <table id="tblStyle">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>DealerRef</th>
                        <th>DTCreated</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, cannot believe I missed something so obvious as this. Greatly appreciated.